# Pulling an integer out of an object and assigning it to a variable

Tags: javascript

If I have an object that contains a number, like this:`objNum = {Num:"12345"}` and I want to put the contents of Num into an array, how would I go about that.  I have tried using objNum.Num, like this: `intAr = objNum.Num`but when I try to call the index of the array at that point, I only get the first number, or 1.  What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `intAr = [objNum.Num]` is what you are looking for?

Comment: I think Niet beat ya to it, but that's what worked, yes.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have to declare the array, then `push` the value to it:

```
var intAr = [];
intAr.push(objNum.Num);
```

Or

```
var intAr = [objNum.Num]
```

Comment: Or just do `intAr = [objNum.Num];` ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - Ahh, trying to type it faster than you can comment!

Comment: But not fast enough :p

Comment: Niet's answer worked since I had actually declared the array earlier in my code.  Thank you both, I really appreciate it.